# Google Cloud Datastore Update Entity: Node.js Client

Tags: node.js, database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

How to update GCP datastore entity in nodejs.

```
// Saves the entity
datastore
.save(task)
.then(() => {
  console.log(`Saved ${task.key.name}: ${task.data.description}`);
})
.catch(err => {
 console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
```

Usually save function is storing the data and if we send the existing the data it is updating fine. But if we miss some columns then it is nullifying those columns. Is there any function to update entity in datastore.

Answer (score 2):

> `save()` in datastore overwrites the entity. If you want to do an
>   update :

1. Get the entity.
2. update the relevant fields in the entity.
3. use `save()` to update.

To avoid race conditions, datastore `transaction` can be used

Comment: I'm doing this approach as of now.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that you are confused about why updating an entity with, say 8 valid properties, will have 2 properties nulled if you only provide 6/8 properties in the update.

This is by design as `Datastore` will write the entire entity with `save()`. What you want to do is force `save(method=upsert, yourdata)`, and a shortcut is to use the `upsert()` method.

Comment: Stil it is endup with empty data.

Comment: var JSONObject = {
   "Device_Key": 123,
   "DeviceName": "abc"
}

var key = datastore.key([DB_CONFIG.DBNAME, ("Device_Key", JSONObject.Device_Key)]);
datastore.save({
   key: key,
   data: JSONObject
}, function(err) {
   if (err) {

       LOGGER.debug("Data entry Failed:" + err);
       callback(err)
   } else {

       callback({
           "code": "200"

       })
   }
})

Comment: But you still haven't explicitly set a method here, to `upsert`. You're letting the library infer it. A shortcut is to use the `upsert()` method directly which is `save()` with `method='upsert'` forced. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.4.x/Datastore#upsert.

Answer (score 1):

reading the "save" documentation at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Datastore -

> By default, all properties are indexed. To prevent a property from being included in all indexes, you must supply an excludeFromIndexes array.

I assume that you get null fields because they're indexed. try to remove indexes from fields that may not exist.

Comment: How can I remove indexes from fields.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Datastore#save (`excludeFromIndexes`) and https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes

Answer (score 1):

If you use [gstore-node](https://github.com/sebelga/gstore-node) there is an update() method on the Model that does this for you.
gstore will do (in a transaction):

- Get the entity in the Datastore
- Merge the data you pass with the entity fetched
- save the entity back in the Datastore.

Here is the documentation of the update() on Model: https://sebelga.gitbooks.io/gstore-node/content/model/update-method.html